# Getting StackOverflowError when using JAVA API to implement Employee example

Tags: java, xls, jxls

I am trying to implement the standard example from GettingStarted guide without the XLS Markup. Instead I am using the Java API directly.

Following is the code:

```
InputStream template = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/object_collection_template.xls"); 
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Transformer transformer `enter code here`= TransformerFactory.createTransformer(template, outputStream);
XlsArea xlsArea = new XlsArea(new CellRef("Template!A1"), new Size(4, 5), transformer);
EachCommand eachCommand = new EachCommand("employee", "employees", xlsArea);
xlsArea.addCommand(new AreaRef("Template!A4:D4"), eachCommand);

Context context = new Context();
context.putVar("employees", data);

xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Template!A1"), context);
transformer.write();
```

Unfortunately this leads to a StackOverflowError:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2380)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2422)
    at org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiUtil.isJxComment(PoiUtil.java:73)
```

According to the debugger the line 
`Size size = area.applyAt(currentCell, context);`

in method org.jxls.command.EachCommand.processCollection is added infinitely to the stack.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: first of: you're showing not enough of your code. to which line of your code does the stacktrace point?

Comment: @Stultuske is right. You need to show more code. As for the stack overflow error. It usually displays with recursion, where the code continually adds methods to the stack. Find out what keeps calling methods.From the exception, it's probably isJxComment()

Comment: added findings from debugging session.